# Multiple writes in Aerospike Java

Tags: java, aerospike, aerospike-loader

I am reading the **CSV File** in **Java**, Now i want to Stored the data present in **CSV File to Aerospike**. i want to do batch processing, is there is any solution for this, as per my research **Aerospike** does not support batch processing for write. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aerospike does not support batch writes at the moment.

You should check out the aerospike-loader app which imports data into Aerospike from CSV files:

https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-loader/

Comment: ..thnx for your reply, i am getting error when i am running the cammand ./run_loader "Could not find or load main class com.aerospike.load.AerospikeLoad".

Comment: Were you able to build the package using maven by running `mvn install`?

Comment: ..thnx @jan-hecking ..its work ...u solved my problem.